# How do I monitor a subset of logins with sysadmin role to find out if they are still in use?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, monitor

How do I monitor a certain subset of logins that have the sysadmin role to find out if they are still in use.  I would like to remove the logins but, do not want to run the risk of disabling them if they are being used.

I found the following code on mssqltips.com that almost works but, it generated about 5 million records a day on the test server and I do not know why.  Does anyone have another solution or know how to fix this code so it only the table when a login with sysadm role logs into the server?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AuditSysAdminLogin
(AuditEventId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
EventTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
ServerLogin NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_AuditSysAdminLogin PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (AuditEventID));
GO

USE master; 
GO 

CREATE TRIGGER trigLogon_CheckForSysAdmin 
            ON ALL SERVER 
            FOR LOGON 
            AS 
    BEGIN 
    IF EXISTS ( 
        SELECT sp.principal_id 
            FROM sys.server_role_members srm 
                    JOIN sys.server_principals sp 
                    ON srm.member_principal_id = sp.principal_id 
            WHERE role_principal_id = ( 
            SELECT principal_id  
                FROM sys.server_principals  
                WHERE NAME = 'sysadmin') 
                AND ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = sp.NAME) 
        BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO DBAWork.dbo.AuditSysAdminLogin 
            (EventTime, ServerLogin) 
                VALUES 
            (GETDATE(), ORIGINAL_LOGIN()) 
        END; 
    END; 
GO
```

Comment: The platform is Microsoft SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: Thank you for the improved tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks like it would work as designed.  Sounds like you actually have sysadmin accounts logging in 5 million times per day.  If you don't need to record every single login, and you're okay with just storing the most recent login time, you can change your trigger to perform a merge like the following (the table should be truncated before implementing this):

```
MERGE AuditSysAdminLogin AS audit
USING (SELECT sp.principal_id
        FROM sys.server_role_members srm 
        JOIN sys.server_principals sp 
        ON srm.member_principal_id = sp.principal_id 
        WHERE role_principal_id = ( 
        SELECT principal_id  
        FROM sys.server_principals  
        WHERE NAME = 'sysadmin') 
        AND ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = sp.NAME) AS NewLogin
ON NewLogin.Principal_Id = audit.ServerLogin
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET audit.EventTime = GETDATE()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ServerLogin, EventTime) VALUES (Principal_ID, GETDATE());
```

If you'd like to capture login counts, you could also add a `BIGINT` field and have the merge statement increment it.

Note - running this type of trigger could have a dramatic impact on your SQL Server's performance.  I don't recommend running it long-term.